# How to load all href links in a separate window

Tags: javascript, html, email, asp-classic, frame

I am loading an HTML content parsed from an email to a frame. If the email contains an href link, it tries to open the link in its frame but I'd like to make it open in a new tab.

Normally, I'd do this by setting the target to _blank in the href, but the href tags are being read straight from the EML files, so unless if there's a better way, it seems like the only way I can accomplish this is to parse the HTML tags that is being read, find all href links and add the target to it. If possible, I'd like to avoid this option because parsing html adds a lot of downside to performance in general.

If anyone knows an elegant way of achieving this, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not very elegant or semantic, but as a quick and dirty solution you can print a base tag before the first link:

```
<base target="_blank">
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_target.asp for more info.

Comment: This is the most simple a solution to this problem will get. Love it.

Comment: Pure awesomeness. +99999999 if I could.

Comment: Considering the [base element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/document-metadata.html#the-base-element) must be in the head and A elements must be in the body, there's a fair bet it will be before the first link. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Yes, but apart from the recommendation, browsers support base tags in the body or even multiple for different parts of the site.

Comment: Won't links after the frame also load in a new window?

Comment: @MichaelTheriot You will need to add the base tag inside the frame.

Comment: @Oliver—not in IE 8 (and probably other versions and browsers). Base elements in the body are ignored regardless if they're inline or added by script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery...

```
$('#frame a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
});
```

Comment: Rather `this.href`, less to type and more efficient.